# check column has the same string

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to check if a dataframe column has the same string.
for example, below dataframe in columns AAA, I want to check if all string is Jack, so the function call should return true!

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'AAA' :
    ['Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack'],
    'BBB' :
    ['January', 'February', 'February', 'April', 'January'],
    'CCC' :
    [85, 96, 55, 64,60]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(len(df['AAA'].unique()) == 1)
```

unique can be used to check value is the same, but I need to check the string is Jack as well.

Comment: `df['AAA'].eq('Jack').all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following modification:

```py
data = {
    'AAA' :
    ['Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack'],
    'BBB' :
    ['January', 'February', 'February', 'April', 'January'],
    'CCC' :
    [85, 96, 55, 64,60]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

is_all_jack = len(df['AAA'].unique()) == 1 and df['AAA'].unique()[0] == 'Jack'
print(is_all_jack)
```

Answer (score 0):

try value_counts

```
df['AAA'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'AAA': ['Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack'],
    'BBB': ['January', 'February', 'February', 'April', 'January'],
    'CCC': [85, 96, 55, 64, 60]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

is_same_string = (df['AAA'] == 'Jack').all()

print(is_same_string)
```

Output: `True`